# Good books to learn complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I’m currently taking a complex analysis course, and I seem to understand most of the material well. However, there are a few topics that are not well explained in the Brown Churchill’s book. (I’m using the 8th edition.) Any recommendations of other complex analysis books that will be a good study aid alongside this book? Perhaps some that offer more detailed example exercises?

Comment: It matters what these topics are that you want further explanation of, or more detail in

Comment: There are many questions like this here. Search for them.

Comment: I think "Complex Variables with Applications" by S. Ponnusamy Herb Silverman is a good book for a beginner.